# Parse SDK Javascript Subscription Query

Tags: javascript

Estou implementando o Parse SDK para JavaScript e estou trabalhando com o "subscription" ouvinte em tempo real de alterações da consulta.

Porém, [de acordo com o manual](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#live-queries), o `object` apenas retorna o `objectId`.

Analisando o depurador do `WebSocket`, pode se observar que ele envia ao cliente o conteúdo do objeto criado/atualizado/apagado.

```
let query = new Parse.Query('teste');
let subscription = await query.subscribe();

subscription.on('create', (object) => {
  console.log('Criou ID: ' + object['id']);
});
```

O pedido de ajuda é o seguinte (Não encontrei na documentação do Parse), como realizo a leitura do conteúdo enviado pelo WS? Assim não preciso executar uma nova query para ler o objeto.